# Seeking advice on safeguarding my manuscript

Tags: copyright, editing, legal

I'm an Australian writer who is contemplating sending my manuscript to a novel editor in America. I'm concerned about the possibility of my work being claimed by someone else. Given my limited understanding of American copyright laws, could anyone please advise me on how to prevent this worst-case scenario from occurring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a new writer keep from getting scooped?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/28235/how-does-a-new-writer-keep-from-getting-scooped)

Answer (score 2):

No respectable publisher or agent will steal your story or ideas, because if this came out no one would ever want to work with them again and they would be out of business.

You will find more answers in the many duplicate questions:

- [How to secure my written work from being stolen or copied before publishing?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/21552/how-to-secure-my-written-work-from-being-stolen-or-copied-before-publishing)
- [How does a new writer keep from getting scooped?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/28235/how-does-a-new-writer-keep-from-getting-scooped)
- [Should I copyright my material before sending to my publisher?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35680/should-i-copyright-my-material-before-sending-to-my-publisher)
- [Pitching an RPG to a publisher: what to bring and how to safeguard the work](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/36306/pitching-an-rpg-to-a-publisher-what-to-bring-and-how-to-safeguard-the-work)
- [Is there a format I can save my poems in that will make the publisher unable to copy and paste?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/is-there-a-format-i-can-save-my-poems-in-that-will-make-the-publisher-unable-to)
- [How much should I reveal about my book idea to a publishing house representative?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/how-much-should-i-reveal-about-my-book-idea-to-a-publishing-house-representative)
- [What if my published short story is made a movie or a novel, without my permission?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/38514/what-if-my-published-short-story-is-made-a-movie-or-a-novel-without-my-permissi)